# I/O to Screen/Standard Output

Tags: c, io

I noticed that in any program that I write, the time taken to execute is significantly slower if I do a lot of printing to the monitor (i.e. `printf` or `fprintf (stderr, "...")`).

I figured that writing to the disk will be slow, because of the physical limitations of the disk. I'm not sure why printing to the screen should slow the program down significantly.

Comment: Switching between user and kernel space, pipelining, etc. etc.

Comment: Basically because stdio is (mostly) line buffered, and every write invokes a system call. BTW: on a virtual terminal there is also the terminal emulator eating a lot of cycles. On a multi-CPU machine one CPU is busy doing the scrolling and buffering, while another feeds it the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to a terminal is not exactly fast and is not designed to be fast since usually the only stuff that goes to stdout are pieces of information for the user who is bound by how fast he or she can read stuff.

When you write to the terminal on eg. linux, the following stuff happens (maybe). The kernel is  being called between each two consecutive steps:

1. Your program issues a write system call to write data.
2. The kernel resumes your terminal emulator and yields the data written to the terminal device
3. The terminal emulator renders its frame's new state and sends this to the X server
4. The X server manipulates memory mapped display regions
5. The kernel tells your graphics card to swap buffers

And those are a lot of steps... Since terminal output is usually only line-buffered, this occurs pretty often.

Comment: Could you describe what you (and everyone else on this thread) mean by "line-buffered"? Are there other kinds of buffering? What is buffering  in the context of terminal output?

Comment: @poundifdef line-buffered means: when you call a function that writes to a line-buffered output, the data is stored in a buffer and written if either the buffer is full or if there is a newline.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the type of screen, the size of it, the graphics card or whatever the output goes through, yes, printing stuff can add significant time to the execution time. It is very likely that printing to disk is actually faster - disks can take several megabytes per second (theoretically around 300-600MB/s on a modern SATA drive, but in reality, sooner or later it will be slower than that, as the disk actually needs to move the data onto the platters inside the disk - but they also have large caches, so writing 16MB or 32MB can take quite some time). Try adding some timestamps to your code (if you haven't already) and compare `myprog` with `myprog > file` and `myprog > /dev/null` (or NUL: if you are windows), and see which one takes more time - I bet it's the one going to the screen - and writing to the null device is the fastest, but only a little bit.

The biggest problem with printing to screen is the scrolling - it means "shuffle everythng", and even with clever hardware, it can be quite a lot of pixels to shuffle around. Bear in mind that modern graphics cards are much more oriented towards drawing 3D, which is done in quite a different way from scrolling 2D text screens.

And of course, on top of that, your application itself takes more time because you are calling printf or similar functions, which aren't entirely trivial functions, so if you print a lot of stuff, printf in itself takes some time - for programs with simple code, this can be 10x the time it takes to do the actual work, even if the data goes to "null".

Answer (score 2):

printf() is usually line-buffered when printing to the screen (terminal) which makes the output slower.

You can set the buffer size for `stdout` using **[setvbuf()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setbuf.3.html)**.

Comment: So if I set it to print every say, 100 lines or something then it'd be quicker?

Comment: @Kitchi Maybe. Try to output your data into a file in one go for maximum performance.

Comment: @Kitchi Very likely. Basically buffered output would avoid the overhead in calling printf() for every line.

Comment: setvbuf won't help on the overhead of calling printf every line. It will improve the amount of data that is sent to the screen/disk in one go, because more data is being sent in one big lump. But printf itself will still do exactly the same thing - it's like the difference between taking one empty beer-can to the recycling box or getting a bag to collect the whole lot in one go. But you still need to pick up each beer can.